# Mock Database with ID column

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I'm (fairly) new to TDD, so be gentle!

I am using CodeFirst to create my application in C# using EF6 in VBS2015 Community.

I have an Interface created for my data access and am able to create a Mock Database in memory for Unit testing.

Each of my Models has a unique identifier column which is named Id (For example, UserID)

Ok, so when I add records to my Mock database, I need to have it create a new ID value for the record, as I reference this in later code. How do I do this with a generic set, when each table has a unique ID column? Do I have to mock out each table independently?

My database interface looks like this:

```
Namespace Labinator2016.Lib.Headers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    public interface ILabinatorDb : IDisposable
    {
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
        void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void Delete<T1>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T1, bool>> target) where T1 : class;
        void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        void SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My Mock Database then looks like this:

```
namespace Labinator2016.Tests.TestData
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Lib.Headers;
    using Labinator2016.Lib.Models;
    class FakeDatabase : ILabinatorDb
    {
        public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class
        {
            return this.Sets[typeof(T)] as IQueryable<T>;
        }
        public void Dispose() { }
        public void AddSet<T>(IQueryable<T> objects)
        {
            this.Sets.Add(typeof(T), objects);
        }
        public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            this.Added.Add(entity);
            IQueryable<T> temp = this.Sets[typeof(T)] as IQueryable<T>;
            List<T> existing = temp.ToList();
            existing.Add(entity);
            Sets[typeof(T)] = existing;
        }
        void ILabinatorDb.Delete<T1>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T1, bool>> Target)
        {
        }
        public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            this.Updated.Add(entity);
        }
        public void Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            this.Removed.Add(entity);
        }
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            this.saved++;
        }
        public Dictionary<Type, object> Sets = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        public List<object> Added = new List<object>();
        public List<object> Updated = new List<object>();
        public List<object> Removed = new List<object>();
        public int saved = 0;
    }
}
```

Currently, I have some code that gets a user object from a user table, based on a name. If it doesn't exist, then one is created first. Here is my code:

```
User existingUser = this.db.Query<User>().Where(u => u.UserName == newUserName).FirstOrDefault();
if (existingUser == null)
{
    User userToAdd = new User();
    userToAdd.UserName = newUserName;
    userToAdd.Password = PasswordHash.CreateHash("password");
    this.db.Add<User>(userToAdd);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
    existingUser = this.db.Query<User>().Where(u => u.EmailAddress == nu).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So, am I using the wrong approach completely in my application, or is there a way to mock out this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you are testing its a little hard to say but I suspect you could use a mocking framework like Moq to do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Below is a simple example on how you might test that a new user is created if they don't exist in the database and how they are not if they do (Using Moq).

```
    public class UserManager
{
    private readonly ILabinatorDb _liLabinatorDb;

    public UserManager(ILabinatorDb liLabinatorDb)
    {
        _liLabinatorDb = liLabinatorDb;
    }

    public void CreateNewUser(string userName)
    {
        User existingUser = _liLabinatorDb.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

        if (existingUser == null)
        {
            User userToAdd = new User();
            userToAdd.UserName = userName;

            _liLabinatorDb.Add<User>(userToAdd);
            _liLabinatorDb.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenAUsernameWhenNoUserExistsInDatabaseThenNewUserCreated()
    {
        var mockDatabase = new Mock<ILabinatorDb>();
        mockDatabase.Setup(a => a.Query<User>()).Returns(new List<User>().AsQueryable());
        var userManager = new UserManager(mockDatabase.Object);
        userManager.CreateNewUser("UserDoesntExistInDatabase");

        mockDatabase.Verify(a => a.Add(It.IsAny<User>()),Times.Once);
        mockDatabase.Verify(a => a.SaveChanges(),Times.Once);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GivenAUsernameWhenUserExistsInDatabaseThenNewUserNotCreated()
    {
        var mockDatabase = new Mock<ILabinatorDb>();
        var mockedUsers = new List<User>
        {
            new User {UserId = 2, UserName = "UserExistsInDatabase"}
        };

        mockDatabase.Setup(a => a.Query<User>()).Returns(mockedUsers.AsQueryable());
        var userManager = new UserManager(mockDatabase.Object);
        userManager.CreateNewUser("UserExistsInDatabase");

        mockDatabase.Verify(a => a.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Never);
        mockDatabase.Verify(a => a.SaveChanges(), Times.Never);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it without creating new Manager Classes with right framework ([Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/)), I've recreated first example, to show the differences. It's shorter and clearer:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestAddWithEmptyDb()
{
    //Arrange
    var fakeDb = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<FakeDatabase>(Members.CallOriginal);
    var userList = new List<User>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDb.Query<User>()).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(userList.AsQueryable());

    //Act
    UnderTest test = new UnderTest();
    test.get("newName");

    //Assert
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithArguments(() => fakeDb.Add<User>(null)).Matching(a => (a[0] as User).UserName == "newName");
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => fakeDb.SaveChanges());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issues in our project.

This is the conclusion we came to:

- We do not mock the database with logic. After adding an item, it is not found by a query automatically. The DB-mock is not a fully functional in-memory-database. You have to mock each method call independently (using a mocking framework). This reduces the amount of complexity of the test framework drastically.
- We need to **get an ID after adding it to the database** as well. There is a bit of reflection code in our default mock setup that sets the Id property with some arbitrary value. Our Id properties all have the same name by convention.
- To test logic which needs some kind of real database, like testing complex queries, we use an in-memory SQLite database (with NHibernate which supports it more or less transparently).
- To test logic separate from database access and queries, I would hide the complex queries behind an interface and mock that. Instead of accessing the IQueriable direcly (which is almost impossible to mock), have an interface with methods like `GetUserByName(name)`, `GetAllActiveUsers()` and so on.